# View in browser content in alternate language

Tags: ampscript, language

We have emails that have the view in browser -- `<a alias="View-In-Browser" href="%%view_email_url%%" style="text-decoration:none; color:#0072CE;" target="_blank">View in browser</a>`-- enabled. However, we want to make it so that when the end user does view the email in browser, they can toggle between English or French.

Is this something that's possible? Ideally, the view in browser in English / French would allow for the dynamic content to still be visible while viewing the email in either language (i.e. if the end user received the email in French, but wanted to see it in english, they could use a "view in browser - English" button).

The current workaround is using a button that leads to a "toggle" page which mimics the email, but removes any dynamic content that's enabled by ampscript.

Thanks in advance!